# Hide Baseline in Stem Plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am new-ish to Matplotlib.

I made a stem plot (aka lollipop) using Python/Matplotlib. These kinds of plots have style settings: `linefmt`, `markerfmt`, `basefmt`.

For instance, I can change the color of the baseline like so:

```
plt.stem(X, Y, basefmt="m")
```

I'd like to see the points and the stems, but I don't want to see the actual baseline. What command/format code do I need to "hide" the baseline? Or am I approaching this wrong?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can do it all in one line:

`plt.stem(X, Y, basefmt=" ")`

Comment: This answer may be obsolete. I get Exception has occurred: ValueError Do not know how to convert ' ' to dashes with Matplotlib 3.3.2

Answer (score 7):

An alternative to brian_o's answer is to set the `visible` property to `False`:

```
(markerline, stemlines, baseline) = plt.stem(X, Y)
plt.setp(baseline, visible=False)
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like `stem` returns a triplet, the third value of which is the baseline object. It can then be manipulated with a `setp` command.

```
m,n,baseline = plt.stem(X, Y, basefmt="m")
plt.setp(baseline, 'linewidth', 0)
```

The code seems to work, but in my opinion it's ultra hacky. Can anyone with a better understanding of default args or keywords do better?